# Admin panel of the website is being accessed without verification

Tags: php, security, authentication

Admin panel is working fine for normal users! It requires password to access it but when I access it using acunetix's http editor it opens the admin panel without verification.
I'm using a function to check if admin is logged in. If not then redirects to login page!
Here's the code of function please help me in this! Thanks.

--> `full()` function is  `mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchar());`

--> `acunetix` is well application vulnerability tester.

```
function admin_check() {
global $users, $mysqli;

if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
    $username = full($_COOKIE['username']);
    $password = full($_COOKIE['password']);
    $id = full($_COOKIE['id']);
    if(is_numeric($id)){
        $id = $id;
            if($id < 0){
                $id = (-1)*$id;
            }
    }
    else {
        $id = 10;
    }


    $query = "SELECT * FROM $users WHERE username = '{$username}' and password = '{$password}' and id = $id ";
    $query_process = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
        if(!$query_process){
            die_message("There was some error checking admin login");
        }

    $check_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_process);
    if($check_rows != 1){
        header("location: login.php");
    }
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_process)){
        $admin_role = $rows['admin_role'];
    }
    if($admin_role != 1){
        header("location: logout.php");
    }


}//end of first if

else {


    header("location: login.php");
}
}// end of function
```

Comment: You are storing login criteria **in cookies**. Facepalm!

Comment: Have you done any debugging to narrow down the problem? Does the acunetix tool somehow cause page to generate output before header calls such that they no longer work? You might consider not having the function control headers, but rather have function just return boolean value as to whether user is admin and have main application logic handle redirection.

Comment: Cookie-based username and password? Not good at all. You best put your website "on hold" till you fix this and use a different method.

Comment: thats why I remove the login page from my site Admin Panel. http://asimishaq.com/admin/

Answer (score 0):

i guess one mistake can be because the script keeps on executing even after 
**header("location: login.php");**
a possible way to remove it is by die() function. just add die() after every header redirect you are making.